# curl alternative to bypass client_max_body_size

Tags: curl

I am trying to put an archive in artifactory, but I have an ngnix in front of it which I cannot configure it and when I am trying upload `.zip` archives via  `curl -k -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:<API_KEY>" -X PUT "https://artifactory/.." -T <FILE>.zip`, ngnix won't let me due to client_max_body_size:

```
<html>
<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to put the file in chunks or a workaround for this issue ? Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: drop `-X PUT`. That's hurts my soul.

Then, `-k` is hopefully only something you use while experimenting

Finally: `-H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"` is your friend. It will make curl send the request chunked instead of passing the size upfront.

```
curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:<API_KEY>" "https://artifactory/.." -T <FILE>.zip -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
```

Comment: Thx for the answer Daniel, indeed the `-k` is just to test , but out of curiosity why `-X PUT` 
 is wrong ?

Comment: `-X` is always wrong when the method is already set/implied by another option. In this case you use `-T` so it already makes `PUT`.